# Why would someone write an if condition containing a float like this?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, precision

I am looking through some code previously written by a senior developer in my company and I am curious about the reasoning behind the somewhat convoluted looking if statement they wrote (I would ask them directly if possible).

The code is intended to check if temperature readings from a sensor are valid. I believe negative readings were valid at the time, which explains the use of `std::abs()` and comparison of that to 0.000001 instead of just using `temperature > 0`, however I am unsure why they chose to subtract `0.` as well. I have included a minimum working example, but the focus of my question is on why the statement includes the `- 0.` (just to convert float to a double? That seems to be what VSCode thinks it does) and if my assumption about needing to accept negative values while also needing to invalidate (very near) zero readings in the form of floats sounds correct.

```
#include <optional> 
#include <iostream>

void check_temp(std::optional<float> prev_temp, float cur_temp){

    if ((!prev_temp && std::abs(cur_temp - 0.) < 1e-6) ||
        (prev_temp && std::abs(prev_temp.value() - cur_temp) > 100.0))
    {
        std::cout << "Temperature error detected!\n";
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::optional<float> prev_temp = std::nullopt;
    float cur_temp = 0;

    while(1){
        std::cout << "Enter temp: ";
        std::cin >> cur_temp;
        check_temp(prev_temp, cur_temp);
        prev_temp = cur_temp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**And to be very clear, the specific line (condition) I am looking for clarification on is:**

```
(!prev_temp && std::abs(cur_temp - 0.) < 1e-6)
```

Comment: It promotes the value to `double`; don’t know why that matters.

Comment: Recommendation: If they're still at the company, or available to bribe with a beer or whatever their poison is, ask 'em. Even if someone here can give a good answer, there could be a really neat story, like ["Lose the duck."](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/) (see point 5).

Comment: Mind you it could ba as simple as , "Well, m'boy, back when we were chiseling the code into the cave walls for rev 0.01, the compiler optimized this better. Worked, so we kept it."

Comment: @user4581301 would if I could, unfortunately not an option so I was hoping there was some detail I've yet to come across which could explain it. The person who wrote it was pretty good about being very intentional and doing things as close to the 'right' way as possible (as far as Ive seen up to this point), but that's certainly always a possibility. I appreciate the feedback either way.

Comment: I'd imagine that it is not a matter of functionality, but clear expression of intent for later readers. This says to me they are checking for a value that is effectively 0 while being aware of and allowing for the inexact nature of machine floating point representations. Without the - 0., that point is more casual and might not be as clear and more likely to be missed by those less familiar with floating point issues. This is also a standard form to write it, rather than using a special case format that is only valid for the value 0.

Comment: @AviBerger I hadn't considered the readability aspect because it didn't improve that for me (as I just assumed there was something else I didn't know about floating point numbers) but I can see now how that could've been the intent; Interesting perspective.

Comment: Don't know if it is relevant, but another question I would be asking (of the HW setup, not here) is: What reading values would result if the sensor is disconnected or has failed?

Comment: You should show the actual code. A [mre] is needed for debugging question, but this is not directly a debugging question. It is an inquiry into the original intent of working code, and context and details revealed by the original code may be important.

Comment: It should be considered that a cause of some of the code is error or misunderstanding by the programmer. The fact they are a senior developer does not preclude this (and they may not have been a senior developer when they wrote it). Subtracting zero is almost certainly unnecessary, unless there was some compiler bug they needed to work around. However, in that case, failing to document that is an error. For that matter, failing to document the code is a deficiency.

Comment: One has to wonder why the temperature being near zero would be an error, since more negative and more positive values are allowed. If a temperature can be −3 and can be +3, certainly there must be some time when it is in fact 0, so treating that has an error would be a mistake. This code is suspect.

Comment: @AviBerger: Floating-point representations are exact. Floating-point operations approximate real-number operations. This is specified by IEEE-754 and other floating-point specifications, and this model is crucial for correctly designing, analyzing, proving, and debugging floating-point software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> clarification on:

```
(!prev_temp && std::abs(cur_temp - 0.) < 1e-6)
```

`!prev_temp` certainly tests if a previous temperature exist.  Since it does not (in this clause), code continues "as if"  previous temperature was zero.  The subtraction with 0.0 instead of 0.0f  is an oversight on the original programming.  The same functionality and simpler code would have been `std::abs(cur_temp - 0.0f)` for illustrative purposes.

There is *no reason* for a `double` constant `1.0e-6` except for a pedantic compare against `1.0e-6` vs `1.0e-6f` - which are different values.  IOWs, `1.0e-6f < 1.0e-6` might be true, so the equivalent replacement is `std::abs(cur_temp) <= 1e-6f` - note the `<=`.

The compare against the `double`  `100.0` again is weak programming.  Nothing gain by using `double`.  It might not emit different code had is been `100.f` with a good optimizing compiler.

IMHO

```
  if ((!prev_temp && std::abs(cur_temp - 0.) < 1e-6) ||
    (prev_temp && std::abs(prev_temp.value() - cur_temp) > 100.0))
```

better as

```
  if ((!prev_temp && std::abs(0.0f - cur_temp) < 1e-6f) ||
    (prev_temp && std::abs(prev_temp.value() - cur_temp) > 100.0f))
```

The *only* reason I see for masterfully coding in this fashion is to try to steer the compiler output.  Such coding applies to the compiler of that vintage.  Better now to code for clarity.

Comment: I am assuming that you meant "IOWs, 1.0e-6f < 1.0e-6 might be true," but please correct me if I am wrong. My only other question is, would your suggestion of the <= operator vs < imply that they likely meant to check if cur_temp was below or equal 1.0e-6 using a more precise data type instead of using <=, as that is how I am reading it

Comment: @DouglasB Type corrected.

Comment: @DouglasB Yes.  Say the code was contracted to do  something special on `< 1e-6`.  Since neither `double`, nor `float` represent the decimal number exactly, each rounds to a different yet close value- `double` being closer. I doubt that is the reason for `double` constants here, far more likely just casual practices.

Comment: As noted in my comments on the question, code like this **should** be documented, and the fact it is not is a defect in itself. So we already know it was not written with the proper care. Then, note the code allows −3 and +3 for a temperature but not 0. That contrasts with physics; something that is −3 units at one time and +3 units at another must be 0 sometime in between (neglecting hypothetical quantum effects, which I doubt is what the test was intended for). Trying to make sense out of bad code may just produce bad ideas; it is better to assume it is broken and needs to be rewritten.

Comment: Some temp sensors are known to get stuck at 0, that is what they are testing for (probably cooling fans should be off at this temp, so presumption is it should be getting hotter (or vise-versa)); and somehow they know (from the physics) the real temp can never change by 100 or more in one interval.  That assumption might be dangerous--systems can and have caught fire. "< 1e-6" vs " < 0.0" is SOP for some devs.  "std::abs(cur_temp - 0.) < blah" vs. "std::abs(cur_temp - 0.)" is to boolean-ize it.

Comment: "cur_temp - 0."  was to get rid of the "comparing float to double" compile error/warning ("float abs(float arg)" vs. "double abs(double arg)").  Code from senior devs are often over-trusted (like you are doing) leading to less detailed review.

Comment: @Andrew Asserting "over-trusted" is mistaking politeness and range of experience for not over stating the certainty of the senior devs intentions.   IAC, `cur_temp - 0.` is a weak way to get rid of the "comparing float to double" warning.  Instead, simply stay with `float` math as with `std::abs(0.0f - cur_temp) < 1e-6f`, or even simpler with `std::abs(cur_temp) < 1e-6f`.

Comment: I standby my statement, and I missed your point

Comment: Rather than focus on mine and yours, better to address the code, question and answers. This answer addresses the unnecessary mixed use of `double` in a `float` problem and apparently meet OP's concern.  [Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75241215/why-would-someone-write-an-if-condition-containing-a-float-like-this/75241669?noredirect=1#comment132800386_75241669) discusses the rational of the low and values use in the compare - something not addressed here other the the questionable merit of `1.0e-6` instead of `float`: `1.0e-6f`.